# Pinterest API to get proposed pins in feed

Tags: ios, pinterest, pins

It's possible to get user's pin. Also, it's possible to get a list of user's interests. But, how to get a list of pins by interests? Pinterest app shows a feed with proposed pins, but public Pinterest API (https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/) doesn't provide required for me interfaces. Probably I missed something, but is it possible to get a feed with pins using Pinterest SDK API?

Comment: No. They don't want everyone to be able to create a Pinterest clone so easily.